# The sample of "matching_to_many_images.cpp" in OpenCV2.4 can't run

Tags: opencv

I downloaded the OpenCV2.4 and installed it, I am using  VS2008, when I debugging the sample of [`matching_to_many_images.cpp`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/matching_to_many_images.cpp), I found this lines in sample:

```
if( !createDetectorDescriptorMatcher( detectorType, descriptorType, matcherType, featureDetector, descriptorExtractor, descriptorMatcher ) )
{
    printPrompt( argv[0] );
    return -1;
}
```

the `createDetectorDescriptorMatcher()` return false.

why? and how can i do? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. include nonfree.hpp

   > #include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
2. initialize nonfree module before calling createDetectorDescriptorMatcher()

   > initModule_nonfree();